# Show $Tx \in \ell ^2$ for every $x \in \ell ^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(v_n)_{n \geq 1} \in \ell ^2$ be a fixed bounded sequence of real numbers. Define a mapping $T$ on $\ell ^{\infty}$ using the formula $$T(a_1, a_2,...)=(v_1a_1,v_2a_2,...), \, \, \, \, \, x=(a_1,a_2,...) \in \ell^{\infty}$$ Show that $Tx \in \ell ^2$ for every $x \in \ell ^{\infty}$.

---

Here is what I tried:

$Tx=(v_1a_1,v_2a_2,...)(a_1,a_2,...)=(v_1a_1^2,v_2a_2^2,...)=(v_1,v_2,...)(a_1^2,a_2^2,...)=(v_1,v_2,...)x^2$

I am not really getting anywhere. What is the end result meant to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a = (a_1,a_2,...) \in \ell_{\infty}$, $Ta = (v_1a_1,v_2a_2,...)$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v_n ^2 a_n ^2 \le \|a\|_{\infty}^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v_n ^2 = \|a\|_{\infty}^2 \|v\|_2 ^2 < \infty$$

So $Ta \in \ell_2$.

Comment: could you explain a bit more please

Comment: @cooldudeman do you know the definitions of $\ell_{\infty}$ and $\ell_2$?

Comment: yes definitely, just cant figure out how you deduced it is < inf

Comment: $\|a\|_{\infty} = \sup_{n \in N} |a_n| < \infty$ by definition of $\ell_{\infty}$ and $\|v\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v_n^2} < \infty$ by the definition of $\ell_2$.

Comment: Thanks, this $Tx$ notation is so bad! It should say T(x) or something...

Comment: @cooldudeman you're welcome. You should get used to it; that's how linear operators' arguments are usually expressed.